# Issue while Executing XPath Function in Automation anywhere

Tags: xpath, soap, automationanywhere

I'm trying to use Execute XPath Function in automation anywhere.

In the response I'm getting the value as `"MS.Internal.XML.XPath.XPathSelectionIterator"`

XPath looks like :

```
//GetEmployees/Employee/text()
```

I'm sure that xpath is correct since I have tested with Java code.

Looks like the control is returning an object instead of text string.

Is there a way we can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer to  this one by trial and error.

Was trying to parse soap response and I believe it was facing an issue with namespace.

got wit working by using the following expression

string(//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*[name()='GetEmployees']/*name()='Employee'])

Hope this helps and some one could improve it further.